# How long will my battery last and how to calculate it?

Tags: voltage, led, 12v, ampere-hour

I have a 12V 18Ah battery I wish to run through a boost converter at 40v and 2.5A to power a 100w led.

Could someone figure out how long my battery would power my led and show the calculatins/formulas.

Thanks

Comment: Besides that its impossible to do accurately without knowing the efficiency of the boost converter, why didn't the gazillion questions that handle the same topic here answer the question already?

Comment: @PlasmaHH - that is essentially the same question and set of good answers. This question is a duplicate, and so should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods:

**Amp-hour calculation**

Use formula

$$P = V \cdot I$$

For your load the power consumed is \$P = 40 \cdot 2.5 = 100~W\$ as you correctly identified.

If your boost converter is 100% efficient it will consume 100 W. Therefore \$I = \frac {P}{V} = \frac {100}{12} = 8.3~A\$.

Run time is then \$ \frac {18~Ah}{8.3~A} = 2.16~h\$.

**Watt-hour calculation**

This is simpler. Your battery can supply \$12~V \cdot 18~Ah = 216~Wh\$. You have a 100 W load so you could run it for 2.16 h (if you had a 100% efficient booster).

---

Correct these calculations with the efficiency of the boost converter and add in some safety factor for deterioration of battery over time.

---

See @SteveG's comment below regarding de-rating for fast discharge.

Comment: Presuming that this is a sealed lead acid battery, the 18Ah capacity is quoted for a 10h discharge. If you discharge it in 2h then the capacity is around 12.5Ah. The run-time becomes 12.5/8.3 = 1.5h. See the Discharge Characteristics in http://www.yuasabatteries.com/pdfs/NP_18_12_DataSheet.pdf

Comment: I forgot to include that. I've added a pointer to your comment. Thanks.